# How to reference a Hyperlink from another cell?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have to sheets. Sheet `hyper` and sheet `ref`.

`hyper.B2` shows `=HYPERLINK(PathURL&"files/"&A2&".pdf";A2&".pdf")`

`ref.D2` shall show a functioning link, referencing `hyper.B2`.

If `ref.D2=hyper.B2` I only get `myfile.pdf` as text not as link. How can I reference `hyper.B2`/something as it is, not as text?

**edit 1**

`=INDIRECT(hyper.B2)` fails with `#REF!`

Answer (score 0):

You could use =FORMULA to get the actual content of `hyper.B2` and cut out the URL part with text functions. But this won't resolve "inner" functions. Also, thanks to localisation, coming up with the right pattern to cut out the URL part might be tricky.

So here's my advice: Put `=PathURL&"files/"&A2&".pdf"` and `=A2&".pdf"` in separate cells and build the HYPERLINK new in every cell you want to show the functioning link, referencing the URL and link text containing cells.